# CV Lasso/Ridge Regression in R

Tags: r, cross-validation, lasso-regression

I'm trying to run a `cv.glmnet()` lasso and ridge regression but I keep getting the error:

> Error in cbind2(1, newx) %*% (nbeta[[i]]) :
> not-yet-implemented method for <data.frame> %*%

I'm able to run a normal lasso and ridge regression using the formula:

```
ridge <- glmnet(predictors[train_lasso, ], target[train_lasso], alpha=0, 
          family="multinomial")
```

and alpha=1 for the lasso. This code works, but when I use the `cv.glmnet` formula with the same arguments, it draws an error.

The data I'm using is from the DrivenData WaterPump: Pump it Up challenge where the target variable, status_group takes 3 values, ergo the family="multinomial". Here is a dput of my data frame and the code I ran:

```
structure(list(id = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), status_group = c("non functional", 
"functional", "functional", "functional", "non functional"), 
    amount_tsh = c(0, 0, 0, 10, 0), date_recorded = structure(c(15657, 
    15038, 15060, 15859, 15048), class = "Date"), funder = c("Tasaf", 
    "Shipo", "Lvia", "Germany Republi", "Cmsr"), water_quality = c("milky", 
    "soft", "soft", "milky", "soft")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

predictors <- train_final %>%
  select(-id, -status_group)

# One-hot encode the target variable
target <- model.matrix(~ status_group - 1, data = train_final)

grid <- 10^seq(10, -2, length = 100)

### train and test set ###
set.seed(1)
train_lasso <- sample(1:nrow(predictors), nrow(predictors) / 2) 
test_lasso <- (-train_lasso)
y.test_lasso <- target[test_lasso]


# Fit Lasso regression model
lasso.mod <- glmnet(predictors[train_lasso, ], target[train_lasso], alpha = 1, lambda = grid, family="multinomial")

plot(lasso.mod)

### cv lasso ###
set.seed(1)
cv.out <- cv.glmnet(predictors[train_lasso, ], target[train_lasso], alpha = 1, family="multinomial")
```

Again, the lasso.mod looks good as am I'm to plot it, it's just the `cv.glmnet` function that draws the error. Same goes for ridge regression.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the data in `dput` format? Please visit [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).